# Spring Config Server - Property Overrides

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I have multiple services shared the same config server where the config server pulling from Vault the thing I want to enable  spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans for some services so what I used [Property Overrides](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#property-overrides) to let the service (config client) provides the value for this property and by default the property is false in case the service doesn't have the property. The problem that the default value it always return even if the service provided it's own value of that's property is this case false and it totally ignores the one coming from the service, any suggestions?

```
    application:
    name: my-config-server
  profiles:
    active: vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        overrides:
          spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans: ${app.spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans:false}
          spring.boot.admin.client.password: ${app.spring.boot.admin.client.password:defaultAdminPassword}
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.0.1
          kv-version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative Solution

I think you can make use of the `overrideNone` property:

> You can change the priority of all overrides in the client to be more
> like default values, letting applications supply their own values in
> environment variables or System properties, by setting the
> spring.cloud.config.overrideNone=true flag (the default is false) in
> the remote repository.

if you do this your property can just be the default:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        overrides:
          spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans: false
          spring.boot.admin.client.password: defaultAdminPassword
```

---

### Solution

You need to surround the value in quotes to stop the placeholder from resolving. Right now, your config server is setting the property to false on load because it cannot resolve the local property `app.spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans`, thus it is defaulting to `false`. By including the quotes, the property is set to literally `${app.spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans:false}`

In a yaml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        overrides:
          spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans: "${app.spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans:false}"
          spring.boot.admin.client.password: "${app.spring.boot.admin.client.password:defaultAdminPassword}"
```

Comment: after adding the backsplash the service not able to start up:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans' to boolean:

    Property: spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans
    Value: \false
    Origin: "spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans" from property source "bootstrapProperties-overrides"
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to boolean

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Comment: @Kyle It's still resolving the placeholder for some reason. Can you try adding quotes around it? `"\${app.spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans:false}"`

Comment: Thanks George, but still same error, I believe based on the documents you do not need to esacpe in YML files.

Comment: @Kyle Yeah I think the quotes will be enough to escape the placeholder function. The backslash is not needed. "${app.spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans:false}"

Comment: In the documentation, it states `In YAML, you do not need to escape the backslash itself. ` which just means you don't need to escape the backslash like this `\\\`.

Comment: Right, which leads us to the original problem

Comment: @Kyle The original problem was that the placeholder was being resolved. By adding the quotes it is no longer resolving the placeholder and a string literal. The initial property was `${app.placeholder:default}` when it should be `"${app.placeholder:default}"`

Comment: Thanks George but the problem the placeholder resolves always even without the double quotes; the problem is whenever give a default value; default value always override and the service value is ignored.